# .Net standard library for single thread execution

Tags: .net, multithreading

I just wrote this code by hand:

```
class SingleWorkerThread
{
    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SingleWorkerThread));
    public readonly BlockingCollection<Action> tasks = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
    private readonly Thread thread;

    private void executeThread()
    {
        _logger.InfoFormat("Starting execution");
        Action task;
        while( (task = tasks.Take()) != null)
        {
            _logger.InfoFormat("About to execute a task...", task);
            task();
            _logger.InfoFormat("Completed executing task");
        }
        _logger.InfoFormat("Finished execution");
    }

    public SingleWorkerThread()
    {
        thread = new Thread(executeThread);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        tasks.Add(null);
    }

    public void AddTask(Action a)
    {
        tasks.Add(a);
    }

    public void Join()
    {
        // Wait up to 2 seconds for thread to terminate.
        thread.Join(2000);
    }
}
```

I am using it to ensure that all execution of a certain category of tasks is always done by a single thread.

I'd like to avoid "re-inventing the wheel" if possible - is there a standard .Net "queue consuming thread" module that I could use in place of the above?

If not, are there any "gotchas" (i.e. bugs), in the code I just posted?

Comment: A "single thread threadpool" seems a bit of a contradiction. :)

Comment: "I am using it to ensure that all execution of a certain category of tasks is always done by a single thread." Just why ?

Comment: I think your approach is fine (But I would use  `Task` insted of `Thread` + `tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable()` and `tasks.CompleteAdding` instead of adding null action to terminate)

Comment: Sriram - the framework I am plugging into gives me concurrent requests, but in this case they can all only be executed sequentially. The tasks all depend on a single file download - which is the only time consuming action. So each task 1. Checks to see if the file is already there. 2. Downloads the file if it's not there. 3. Reads some information from the file.

Comment: Coding gorilla: true :) I have amended the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this.

This is basically the code:

```
class SingleWorkerThread : IDisposable
{
    private Subject<Action> _subject;
    private IScheduler _scheduler;
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SingleWorkerThread));

    public SingleWorkerThread()
    {
        _scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler()
        _subject = new Subject<Action>();
        _subscription =
            _subject
                .ObserveOn(_scheduler)
                .Subscribe(task =>
                {
                    _logger.InfoFormat("About to execute a task...", task);
                    task();
                    _logger.InfoFormat("Completed executing task");
                });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }

    public void AddTask(Action Action)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(Action);
    }
}
```